# firebase_dynamic_links in Flutter does not work on Android version 13

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase_dynamic_links 5.0.11 and Flutter 3.3.9. I did implement the dynamic link by firebase and it is working as it is expected on Android version 12 or less.
**The problem is just on Android version 13 that the link can not open the app.**
I did find some solutions for android 13 like adding the SHA-256 key to Firebase and adding the android:autoVerify="true" to AndroidManifest. But they do not solve the problem.
Does anyone have any clue about the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved by moving **intent-filter** inside the **activity**.

I changed it from:

```
<activity>
  
        .....

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category 
            android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        .....

        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
           <category 
           android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           <category 
            android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
           <data
            android:host="YOUR_CONTENT_LINK_DOMAIN"
            android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

to

```
    <activity>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category 
         android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category 
          android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:host="YOUR_CONTENT_LINK_DOMAIN"
            android:scheme="https"/>
     </intent-filter>
  
      .....

      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category     
            android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>

      .....

    </activity>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said and I am still having problem.  Did you do any thing else?

Comment: @AimnBlbol any luck? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @imgkl yes, I found instructions at https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links.  Make sure to follow it carefully and do the test at the bottom of the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

check do you have in your manifest

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="YOUR_CONTENT_LINK_DOMAIN"
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I had the same issue on android 13 but on 12 and lower was ok. With this intent filter working ok for me

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I had it on the manifest but your answer caused me to think more about it. The problem got solved by moving this 'intent-filter' inside the 'activity' and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

For Android 13 version intent-filter some minor changes. i was facing same issue i resolved this with bellow code snippet.

if You are using **`flavouring`** in your app then you need to follow bellow steps:

1. add firebase host links to respective flavours under app level `build gradle` file.

   ```
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
       dev {
           resValue "string", "app_name", "APP_NAME-D"
           resValue "string", "dynamic_link_domain", "domain_url_dev"
           dimension "default"
           applicationIdSuffix ".dev"

       }
       staging {
           resValue "string", "app_name", "APP_NAME-S"
           resValue "string", "dynamic_link_domain", "domain_url_stg"
           dimension "default"
           applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
       }

       prod {
           resValue "string", "app_name", "APP_NAME"
           resValue "string", "dynamic_link_domain", "domain_url_prod"
           dimension "default"
       }
   }
   ```
2. AndroidManifest.xml code under activity

   intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">



    // If you are using flavouring

if you not using any flavouring you can try like this
just add in AndroidManifest.xml code under activity

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data 
          android:host="DOMAIN_LINK"
          android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
   <data android:host="${deeplinkHost}" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

For android 13 add **autoverify=true** in android manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I have two problems that create this issue:

1. I have subdomain, and I forgot to add it to the `host` in my manifest
2. I have not submitted my SHA256 to Firebase Console

my full URL from Firebase dynamic link **has subdomain** like this: https://customer.yourOwnDomain.com

so you should include your subdomain in the `host`, and you can also use wildcard `*` to make it even safer like this

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="*.yourOwnDomain.com" // your domain + subdomain, not domain.page.link !!!
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

you also MUST to add your SHA256 to your Firebase console. please follow this documentation: [Android app lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#android-sha256-absent)